# Wpf Expander inside the Listview

Tags: wpf, listview, expander

how to put an expander inside listivew?. I want to show expander as rows in listview.

Comment: You should mark answers to your questions as accepted. This will give you some reputation and encourage more people to give you answers.

Comment: To do that, click the check mark next to your favorite answer for each of your questions. To see all of your questions, click your name at the top of the page.

Comment: put some code here of your listview

Comment: Terrible design idea. Keeping track of which expanders were expanded and which are collapsed is difficult enough; getting users to use it is even worse. Rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this where you define the ListView style to place an expander around the GridViewRowPresenter

```
<ListView.Resources>
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"   Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Expander Header="{Binding ColumnCaption}">
                    <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                    </GridViewRowPresenter>
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>                        
</ListView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the expander in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: It worked..But i also want the listview header to be displayed